Vault 32 residents and Bert
In Season One: Episode 1 of Amazon's Fallout (2024), protagonist Lucy is preparing to marry a 'breeder' from Vault 32. Her best friend Steph Harper is, according to Amazon (Explore: Vault Dwellers: Steph Harper), already married to Bert, himself a previously-arrived breeder from Vault 32.

Steph Harper
A native resident of Vault 33, Steph is Lucy’s best friend. She is married to Bert, a breeder from Vault 32 who was traded for some of Vault 33’s agricultural and mechanical resources. They are currently expecting their first child, but that doesn’t stop Steph from taking part in the Young Piker’s Association or any of her other Vault duties.

Given that Steph is newly pregnant, we can assume that Bert arrived in Vault 33 relatively recently.
During the wedding dinner, Steph flirts with Lucy's new husband, and this makes Bert mad — he angrily stabs at food on Steph's plate.
However, later in the episode, it is revealed that:

 The supposed residents of Vault 32 are instead raiders from the surface posing as Vault Dwellers for the purpose of attacking Vault 33. While there are some hints that their leader may have originally been from Vault 32 before becoming a Raider, at least the majority of them are surface dwellers.

But if that is the case,

 shouldn't Bert have realized that he knew none of these people from the place that he grew up in, and lived his whole life in until perhaps a year ago? Shouldn't he have wondered why he didn't recognize any of them, or at least been asking them after people he did know?


I didn't watch the episode, but just based on what you wrote in your question: how do we know that Bert isn't also a 'fake' Vault 32 dweller (especially since he apparently arrived recently)?

@ChanandlerBong That's possible, but then the subterfuge would have to have been going on for months, perhaps a year.  All the while Vault 33 has been receiving telegrams from Vault 32.  The trick is to get them to open vault doors willingly, from the inside - if that happened once, to plant Bert, why not just attack then instead of waiting a year to have the chance to do it again?

OK, you're right, I missed the attacking part in your question.

Lucy's father's from 31, so maybe Bert too?

@Mithoron According to the Amazon page for Fallout that the OP linked, Bert is from Vault 32.

@galacticninja I didn't see these descriptions, but it was very clearly stated in the series that Steph is from 31, so I doubt she'd need any "breeder" and the descriptions on this site should be taken with a grain of salt.

@Mithoron 'it was very clearly stated in the series that Steph is from 31, so I doubt she'd need any "breeder"' Maybe you have an answer here. I'm assuming that information is revealed only after episode 1. (I only watched episode 1, and I don't recall that information being revealed.) If that were the case, then the Amazon description is incorrect in stating that Steph is a "native resident of Vault 33" and that Bert is "a breeder from Vault 32."

@galacticninja Yeah, later on who's from 31 becomes a major point, it seems. I don't remember anyone in 33 being from 32. If someone was he would recognise the problem immediately.

It may be that my "problem" is based on reading the Amazon promotional page, which may not correspond to what is actually developed in the show.  I have only seen Episode 1.  I would encourage anyone who has watched it all the way through to post relevant quotes in an answer.

The current English version of that Amazon-page doesn't mention any Vault-origin for Steph anymore while the Spanish version still has the same text. So, I'd say take it as an editorial error.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/287367/is-bert-truly-a-traded-breeder-from-vault-32-as-described-on-the-amazon-page-fo

The "Breeding program" was put in place to avoid having children with your close relatives - after 200 years in a close community, almost everyone will become somehow related.
Since Steph is from Vault 31, she is already a newcomer to the gene pool, so she does not need to have a "breeder" from Vault 33, as she wouldn't be related to anyone in 32 - hence Bert is native to 32, contrary to what the Amazon page says.
This claim can be further enforced:

As the OP noted, Steph is pregnant and it is suggested that she married recently
The exchange between vaults 32 and 33 happens every three years - as Lucy mentions it to the council:


So, it is with sound mind and body that I hereby submit my application to the council to participate in the Triennial Trade with Vault 32


Based on the sources we have:

Steph is from Vault 31.
Bert is from Vault 32.


Bert was originally a resident of Vault 32 who was traded to Vault 33 as a "breeder" in exchange for some of Vault 33's mechanical and agricultural resources. He married Steph Harper on March 17, 2294 and they consummated their marriage the same night, with Steph commenting that her wedding dress "got off almost as fast as Bert did." By 2296, they had conceived their first child.
Source: https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Bert_(TV_series)

It isn't stated explicitly that Bert was traded to 33 specifically to marry Steph. It's possible that he was traded with the intention of him being paired with a suitable mate later on. It's at least been 2 years since Steph and Bert got married, but Bert could have come to Vault 33 many years before then. In theory they ought to have paired Bert and Steph with people originally from 33 but apparently for whatever reason they didn't do that.
The other thing is that the Vaults contain hundreds of individuals, and there's obviously trading of people that goes on between Vaults so it isn't necessarily suspicious for Bert to not recognize people from Vault 32.
Also, the people living in the vaults seem to be a tad naiive. Bert doesn't really have any specific reason to be suspicious by that point, so the fact that he didn't recognize these people isn't necessarily strange.
